# How do i autocomplete using Tabnine

Tags: tabnine

I have downloaded tabnine, which helps the developer to not write mistaken words like for example: "helpo" instead of "hello".
But i dont know which button autocomplete the guessed word in every moment. ( The guessed word is on grey). I tried ctrl+enter, alt+enter, which were the most logical, but i am lost.
Someone knows which are the correct keys?

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to provide a description of how you installed tabnine and on which editor. Otherwise there is no way to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's the 'Tab' button. Can be a bit confusing initially.